# how to find length of a side of a quadrangle when all other sides' length are known?

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

[quadrangle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pRHYW.png)

[length DA](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ULSkp.png)

I do not understand from how $DA^2= (AB + BC + CD)^2$.

It appears to me that cosine law has been used after that but I don't understand that either.

Could someone please explain?

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to get from D to A.

The first is just directly
from D to A.

The second is,
considering them as vectors,
not lengths,
from D to C,
then C to B,
finally B to A.

The two must be the same.

Comment: Thank you so much for the reply.

Comment: Do you also have an explanation to what is done in the second step?